# Doesn't keras.layers.Flatten lose information?

Tags: keras, flatten

Brand new to keras and ML in general. I'm looking at https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/, and it uses Flatten between Embedding and Dense because Embedding produces a 2D vector but Dense requires a single dimension.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but why doesn't this lose which words are in which input vectors? How are we able to still know that input #3 was "nice work" and is associated with label #3, 1, for "positive"?

I guess the original dimensions are retained from the original input and then somehow restored for Dense's output? Or am I just totally missing a major conceptual aspect?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 8, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding layer gives you a vector for each word token, so the output is 2-d. We need to use `flatten` before any classifier block.

There is some information lost, for example when we use Convolutional layers, and then flat the feature maps, the spatial information is lost. But we already extract the most important features using Conv layers and we feed those features to fully connected layers.

In your example, the temporal dimension is no longer maintained, usually, it's desired to pass the output of the embedding matrix to an RNN/Conv layer for further feature extraction.

- Flatten only is applied on the non-batch dimension, meaning the examples are still separated (if you mean that).
- For each sample, let's say `nice work`, we get 2 vectors (1 for nice, 1 for work), now we only want to know the overall sentiment from the sentence so, once we extract the features, we can apply flatten.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still missing something though.  
Let's say our inputs are    
`nice job`, label `0`    
`this sucks`, label `1`     
  
Converts to `[[1, 2], [3,4]]`  
  
Flatten turns `[[1,2], [3,4]]` into `[1,2,3,4]`. Any learning happens on `[1,2,3,4]`, not `[[1,2], [3,4]]`, yes? But we need to keep the inputs separate to figure out which patterns apply to matching a given input to its label, right? But haven't we lost the fact that `sample[0]` was `[1,2]` and `sample[1]` was `[3,4]`?  

Obviously it works, so I know I'm missing something basic. Just no idea what. :D

Comment: I told you in the question, the flatten doesn't work on batch dimension (the first axis denoting the sample number), that means [1,2] and [3,4] always stay separated. Also embedding layer gives you a vector for each token so, 1 -> [0.5, 0.2, -0.5] something like that. Also the weights will be multiplied and bias will be added to the text sequence.

Comment: Ok, I _think_ I understand what you're saying, but my main takeaway is that the original samples DO remain separate. (Yeah, I know about the vectorizing and bias, etc. I was just trying to keep it simple and short.) Thanks again! EDIT: Oh, wait, maybe that simplification I introduced smudged over the whole purpose of flatten. Anyway, I'm good to move on now. Thanks for the help.